# How to label a custom colormap legend in mayavi

Tags: python, colorbar, mayavi

I have created a custom colormap in mayavi to match the seismic_r colormap from matplotlib. I am able to plot the colorbar, however I am unable to label it. I have tried some suggestions from googling, such as

```
mesh.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.show_scalar_bar = True
```

However it doesn't seem to work. 
If needed I could make the problem more reproducible.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

seismic=plt.cm.seismic_r(np.linspace(0,1,255))*255
mesh=mlab.mesh(xi[:k],yi[:k],-zi[:k],scalars=res[:k],vmin=0.5,vmax=3.5)
mlab.points3d(stx,sty,np.zeros_like(stx),color=(0,0,0),mode='sphere',scale_factor=2500)
mesh.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table = seismic
mlab.colorbar(orientation='vertical',nb_labels=4,label_fmt='%.1f')
mlab.draw()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, the only problem is that you forgot to send reference to the object you want to display the colorbar for. The method to show legend needs a reference to the object or else it doesn't know what to show the legend for. It might seem kinda counter intuitive, especially if you have only one object in the scene, but you need to think that you can have several objects shown at the same time and then the legend would be different for them.

Here is the code that shows how to properly show the legend for colormap of an object in Mayavi:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 20)

x = np.sin(2 * t)
y = np.cos(t)
z = np.cos(2 * t)
s = 2 + np.sin(t)

points = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, colormap="blue-red", scale_factor=.25)
mlab.colorbar(object=points, title="Points in Mayavi")

mlab.show()
```

Result will be then:
[image: Colorbar for a set of points in Mayavi]

Hope this helps.